# Facebook Integration in a PHP site

Tags: authentication, oauth, facebook, legacy

I am trying to integrate my existing php site with Facebook Login functionality. I currently have a simple login registration username, password and email for activation and their details are stored in a MYSQL database. I want to add additional login access for Facebook users. I am worried about how i will be able to integrate my current login access with the new facebook access. Principal on my mind is that all my pages require users to be logged in and i use cookies to store session variables like nickname which i use to build content on my pages.

I am confused by the many approaches I have researched on the web, some are now sadly obsolete and others seem to be half solutions. These three keep re-occurring.

A) Login.php, Register.php and fbReg.php
The login.php and register.php appear when logged in using fb login/register to create a session and pass authentication to the fbReg.php but it just stops there with a blank screen after the page is redirected.

(a snippet from the Register.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: '<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>', status: true,
    cookie: true, xfbml: true});

<?php
    if ($errors == 0) {
    ?>
    $('#form_hidden').hide();
<?php } else { ?>
    checkInput('username');
    checkInput('email');
    checkInput('lastname');
    checkInput('firstname');
    checkInput('password');
    checkInput('password2');
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

B) Legacy Connect Auth
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/
Using the above link I constructed some test scripts just to see if the authentication would work. Fortunately on my site I have third party ads or webframes but followed the steps to the letter building a interstitial_page and redirected page from my main login page. However I keep getting a null session.

(snippet from the php login page)

```
$api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
$interstitial_page = "YOUR_SECURE_URL"; //URL with no 3rd party apps

$url='http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=' . $api_key  
. '&session_version=3&next=' . urlencode($interstitial_page)
. '&v=1.0&return_session=1&fbconnect=1'
. '&cancel_url=' . urlencode($interstitial_page);

echo "Welcome to the Old Auth flow";
echo "<p>";

echo("<a href='" . $url . "'>"
. "<img src='http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/"
. "devsite/facebook_login.gif'></a>");
```

C) OAuth 2.0 protocol 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
when I use this again using the following script:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

I have tried and failed to use this to capture User info for my new facebook site users and store it to MySQL database then integrate this authenticated facebook access with the 'normal' web access user session since that has assocaiated session variables which are used the the user experience.

Any help would be appreciated, im struggling at the moment.

Thanks Michael

i get a blank screen on the fbReg.php

Answer (score 3):

I just did this very thing for my site last week, so I know how hard it is to sort through all of the many methods, many of which are outdated. This was my approach:

1. I placed the "Login in with Facebook" link on my site which redirects to my normal registration page.

   ```
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<? echo $FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>&redirect_uri=http://www.yoursite.com/register.php&scope=email">Log in with Facebook</a>
   ```
2. My registration script looks like this:

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   <head></head>
   <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
   <script>
   FB.init({appId: '<? echo $FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { window.location.reload(); });
   </script>

   function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) 
   {
       $args = array();
       parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);

       ksort($args);
       $payload = '';
       foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
       if ($key != 'sig') {
       $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
       }
       }
       if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
       return null;
       }
       return $args;
   }

   $cookie = get_facebook_cookie($FACEBOOK_APP_ID, $FACEBOOK_SECRET);
   if($cookie)
   { 
       $access_token = $cookie['access_token'];

   }
   $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$access_token;
   $graph = file_get_contents($url);
   if($graph) 
   {

       $fbuser = json_decode($graph);
       $userid = $fbuser->id;
       $email = mysql_real_escape_string($fbuser->email);

       /********************** 
       I placed code here to check if the  email already exists in my database, which means they are already a member. 
       In that case, I retrieve their username and password from the database and automatically log them 
       in by rerouting them to my login script with their crenditials sent as well.
       ***********************/

       /********************** 
       If the email is not already in my database, then I know it's a new user and so I prompt them to make a username here. 
       ***********************/
   }
   //The user either opted to log in using my traditional non-Facebook method, or something went wrong with the FB authentication
   else 
   {

       /********************** 
       Show my normal registration form that prompts for username, email, etc 
       ***********************/
   }
   ```
3. In my login script, I set the username, etc cookies as normal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps immensely. You have a really nice solution, I've just got a few questions to ask. 1) when you have an fb user who is new and needs chooses the facebook route, after you have given them the facebook registration and they are authenticated how to you piggyback them onto a valid session? Is it by rerouting them to a pre-filled login script with credentials? 2) You json_decode to get $userid and $email. Do you use these for insert into your database?  I want to use fb firstname lastname and username in my web app.

Comment: 1. Yes, when I have a new FB user, after they choose a username, then my code basically logs in for them (essentially setting the session cookies), as if they had clicked the traditional login button themselves. So, in your registration script, after you have all the info you need for your new FB user, just reroute to your login script passing on their credentials. I do this using a hidden form that my script self-submits.

2. Yep, once I have the userid and email and then get them to choose a username, I insert them into my database as a new user.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your complete scripts -registration, and amended login page.  (obviously desensitized). My email is michael.mkpadi@michuksltd.com . I am very grateful. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting this error using the registration script like the one you put up above. 
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused

Comment: UPDATE: I replaced file_get_contents with curl. The error handling is better. But When I click on the "Login with Facebook" link on my main site to my registration php the FB.init script  doesnt appear to work as i cant get an FB auth login validation  and the conditional re-directs me to my non-facebook login, even when i now ive got an active fb session. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you are talking about the social plug-ins, but if you are, these [Facebook Plug-ins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) have generators built into the pages which will generate the code you need.

If you are not looking for plugins but instead the information for the users, I still recommend that you run the generators to get the code and see how Facebook gets the information for the users.

Following the path of the simple scripts should get you to where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am after social plug-ins with extensions. A simple Login button, Registration and Authentication. My website already does this but I want to add in a Facebook new user registration and regular user access via Facebook authentication. Nothing I've seen on the facebook dev site or on the wider web seems to give me a clear idea of what i need to begin building in the Facebook access to my existing php files.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/  Login is there, and authentication would be automatically used by this plugin. You could use an i-frame for the registration, since there is no API to register a new user. This iframe could go to the homepage where the signup is located

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i don't think you understand my requirements fully. Let me explain. I want Facebook users who have never used my web app before to be able to register on my MYSQL database and get all the attributes of 'normal' users including a 'website' session not a facebook session. All the new OAuth 2.0 plugins login/register/authentication are really easy to set up but hard to integrate into my existing website as I want to get the user info and save it to my MYSQL user database and create session cookie variables for the user with said user info. legacy stuff dont work now.